# Given $E[Y]=2$ and $Var[Y]=3$, find $Var[3Y+4]$.

Tags: probability, variance

Discrete probability - Variance property

> Given $E[Y]=2$ and $Var[Y]=3$, find $Var[3Y+4]$.

I used algebra and distributed the Var and obtained $$Var[3Y]+Var[4]$$

which would give $13$ but it makes no sense as to how the answer came to be $3^2 \times Var[Y]=27$.

Can someone explain this nonsense?

Comment: ${\rm V}(aX+b)=a^2{\rm V}(X)$. Variance is not linear.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$
Actually
$$\Var(aX+b) = a^2\Var(X).$$

We can verify via one of the variance formulas
\begin{align*}
\Var(aX+b) &= E[(aX+b)^2]-(E[aX+b])^2\\
&= E[a^2X^2+2abX+b^2]-(E[aX]+E[b])^2\\
&=a^2E[X^2]+2abE[X]+E[b^2]-(aE[X]+b)^2\\
&=a^2E[X^2]+2abE[X]+b^2-(a^2(E[X])^2+2abE[X]+b^2)\\
&=a^2(E[X^2]-(E[X])^2)\\
&= a^2\Var(X)
\end{align*}
wherein throughout I used the fact that $E[aX] = aE[X]$ and $E[b] = b$.

So in OP
$$\Var(3Y+4) = 3^2\Var(Y) = 9\cdot 3 = 27.$$

You can find more properties in the Wikipedia article on [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

Comment: It's easier to use the basic definition of variance:
$$
\text{Var}(aX+b) = \mathbb{E}(a(X-\mu))^2 = a^2 \text{Var}(X).$$